# IIS 6 Header too big, how to tune this iis setting

Tags: iis-6, http-headers

IIS 6 seems to be limited (by default at least) to an http header of 16k. I have a 3rd party tool that is talking to the web server (ajax) and sending an http header that is bigger than that. Since I can't control the 3rd party tool, I am hoping to find an IIS 6 setting that will let me increase the maximum header size to 32768 or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the value in

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\MaxRequestBytes`.

This value determines the upper limit of the request header, although there are caveats.  From TechNet:

> Determines the upper limit for the total size of the Request line and
>   the headers. Its default setting is 16KB. If this value is lower than
>   MaxFieldLength, the MaxFieldLength value is adjusted.
>
> Changing this registry key is considered extremely dangerous. This key
>   causes Http.sys to use more memory and may increase vulnerability to
>   malicious attacks.

Here is [**the TechNet article**](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=820129) with more information, including other tuning parameters.